# Error in Apex trigger in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger

I want write an Apex Trigger, but get the following error:

> Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Clm_CallReportData__c to Id at line 8 column 1

I have an object named `Custom_kpi__c`, that has the field `Presentation__c` and I want to assign it the value of `Clm_CallReportData__c.Presentation__c`.

```java
trigger CustomKpiPresentationID on Custom_kpi__c (before insert) {
    list<Custom_kpi__c> a = trigger.new;
    for(Custom_kpi__c ckpi:a) {

        Map<Id,Clm_CallReportData__c> aMap = new Map<Id,Clm_CallReportData__c>([select Presentation__c from Clm_CallReportData__c where Clm_CallReportData__c.id = :ckpi.CallReportData__c]);
        ckpi.Presentation__c = aMap.get('Presentation__c');      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a `Map<Id, Clm_CallReportData__c>` where key is of type `Id` and value is of type `Clm_CallReportData__c`. To fetch the `Presentation__c` value, fetch it from `Clm_CallReportData__c` object.

Updated code:

```
trigger CustomKpiPresentationID on Custom_kpi__c (before insert) {
    List<Custom_kpi__c> a = trigger.new;
    for(Custom_kpi__c ckpi : a) {

        Map<Id,Clm_CallReportData__c> aMap = new Map<Id,Clm_CallReportData__c>([select Presentation__c from Clm_CallReportData__c where Clm_CallReportData__c.id = :ckpi.CallReportData__c]);
        ckpi.Presentation__c = aMap.get(ckpi.CallReportData__c).Presentation__c ;      
    }
}
```

Comment: @OlegSavinkov You can accept it by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green and useful if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

change the code `ckpi.Presentation__c = aMap.get('Presentation__c');` as below.

```
ckpi.Presentation__c = aMap.get(ckpi.CallReportData__c);
```